# How do I shorten the backtrace for a test failure in RSpec 2?

Tags: rspec, backtrace

When my specs hit an error, I get a message like this:

```
Vendor should reject duplicate names
     Failure/Error: user_with_duplicate_email.should_not be_valid
     expected valid? to return false, got true
     # /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-expectations-2.3.0/lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:29:in `fail_with'
     # /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-expectations-2.3.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:44:in `handle_matcher'
     # /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-expectations-2.3.0/lib/rspec/expectations/extensions/kernel.rb:50:in `should_not'
.
.
about 15 more lines
.
.
     # /home/kevin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1592:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
     # /home/kevin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1588:in `loop'
     # /home/kevin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1588:in `block in main_loop'
```

I'm running Ruby 1.0.2, rails (3.0.3), and rspec (2.3.0).  M .rspec configuration file has only two options specified:

> --drb
>   --colour

How do I turn off the extended trace?

Answer (score 13):

In `spec_helper.rb` you can filter backtrace using the following code snippet:

```ruby
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # RSpec automatically cleans stuff out of backtraces;
  # sometimes this is annoying when trying to debug something e.g. a gem

  # RSpec 3:
  # config.backtrace_exclusion_patterns = [
  # RSpec 2:
  config.backtrace_clean_patterns = [
    /\/lib\d*\/ruby\//,
    /bin\//,
    /gems/,
    /spec\/spec_helper\.rb/,
    /lib\/rspec\/(core|expectations|matchers|mocks)/
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I updated it to work with with Rspec 3.2.3. In `spec_helper.rb` put:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.backtrace_exclusion_patterns = [
    /\/lib\d*\/ruby\//,
    /bin\//,
    /gems/,
    /spec\/spec_helper\.rb/,
    /lib\/rspec\/(core|expectations|matchers|mocks)/
  ]
end
```

This is pure gold. Thank you luacassus!

Comment: Why is this not working for me? I know the code loads because I've used `puts 'HERE'` above this config and I see it, but I still get super long backtrace.