# Factories not loading with single test but loads with all tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am following the [rails api book](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_five) but building the code in an engine. The test is at `spec/controllers/concerns/handicap/authenticable_spec.rb` and looks like this

```
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative '../../../../app/controllers/concerns/handicap/authenticable.rb'
  class Authentication
    include Handicap::Authenticable
  end
module Handicap
  describe Authenticable, type: :controlller do
    let(:authentication) { Authentication.new }
    subject { authentication }

    describe "#current_user" do
      before do
        @user = FactoryGirl.create :handicap_user
        request.headers["Authorization"] = @user.auth_token
       authentication.stub(:request).and_return(request)
      end
      it "returns the user from the authorization header" do
        expect(authentication.current_user.auth_token).to eql @user.auth_token
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the test directly i.e. `rspec ./spec/controllers/concerns/handicap/authenticable_spec.rb` I get an error:

```
uninitialized constant Handicap::FactoryGirl
```

However, when I run all the tests i.e. `rspec spec`, it does find the `FactoryGirl` constant and the test fails with

```
undefined local variable or method `request' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::HandicapAuthenticable::CurrentUser:0x007ff276ad5988>.
```

According to this github [issue](https://github.com/kurenn/market_place_api/issues/24),  I need to add `< ActionController::Base` to the Authentication class i.e.

```
class Authentication < ActionController::Base
```

but if I add this in, I get

```
uninitialized constant ActionController
```

I have also tried adding `< Handicap::ApplicationController` but get

```
uninitialized constant Handicap::ApplicationController
```

There appears to be something wrong with my namespacing. There are three symptoms, the fact that `FactoryGirl` cannot be found if I run the test by itself, but is found when all the tests are run. The second is that it cannot find `ActionController` even when all the tests are run. The third is that I need to add the line:

```
require_relative '../../../../app/controllers/concerns/handicap/authenticable.rb'
```

to find the module that is being tested.

How do I fix my namespacing?

The `rails_helper.rb` file is

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../dummy/config/environment.rb', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara-screenshot'
require 'capybara-screenshot/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'capybara/email/rspec'
require 'pp'
require 'chris_api_helpers'
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'factory_girl_rails'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    # Choose a test framework:
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # force test migrations for db:migrate
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
  Capybara::Screenshot.prune_strategy = { keep: 20 }
  Capybara::Screenshot.append_timestamp = false
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'factories')
  FactoryGirl.find_definitions
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

and the `spec_helper.rb` is

```
require 'simplecov' if ENV["COVERAGE"]
SimpleCov.start do
  add_filter '/spec/'
  add_filter '/config/'
  add_filter '/lib/'
  add_filter '/vendor/'
  add_group 'Controllers', 'app/controllers'
  add_group 'Models', 'app/models'
  add_group 'Helpers', 'app/helpers'
  add_group 'Mailers', 'app/mailers'
  add_group 'Views', 'app/views'
end if ENV["COVERAGE"]

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
  #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859037/suppress-backtrace-for-rspec-3
  config.backtrace_exclusion_patterns = [
      /\/lib\d*\/ruby\//,
      /bin\//,
      /gems/,
      /spec\/spec_helper\.rb/,
      /lib\/rspec\/(core|expectations|matchers|mocks)/
    ]
end
```

Comment: Why are you putting your spec in a `module`?

Comment: What does your `spec_helper.rb` look like?  Are you including an appropriate `rails_helper.rb` in it?

Comment: dan-classon, I am putting my spec in a module because it is in a rails engine.  This is standard.

Comment: Greg Tarsa, have added helper files above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that at the top of my file I should have had `require 'rails_helper'`, not ``` require 'spec_helper'``. All my other files had ```require 'rails_helper'`` so when I ran the whole test suite, the rails_helper was being loaded anyway.

Embarrassing, but this Q&A might help someone else that has trouble spotting simple errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be putting specs into modules. This is the cause of problem here. If you need to reference a namespaced class, reference it like `RSpec.describe Handicap::Authenticatable`.

In general, when you are within a namespace and need to reference something explicitly from the 'root' scope, you can prepend it with double-colons. Such as:

```
module Handicap
  class Something
    def do_stuff
      ::FactoryGirl.create(:person)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.  The rails generator for a controller, when run in an engine, does put the spec in the module, so I do not think that is the problem.  ```::FactoryGirl``` did not help either, although thank you for this, because I had seen ```::``` used elsewhere and did not understand it.